# Why is the indirect keyword needed in recursive Swift enumerations?

Tags: swift

I understand what `indirect` does. What I don't understand is why this keyword is needed. Doesn't the compiler have enough information to figure this out on its own?

```
enum Foo {
    case Bar(Foo)
}
```

The code above won't compile unless it's marked `indirect`, but the compiler can already detect that it's indirect because it uses the same type again. Even if we do something more complex, it should be able to figure this out.

```
enum Foo {
    case Bar(Baz)
}

enum Baz {
    case Bob(Foo)
}
```

Even here the compiler has enough information to know that `Foo` and `Baz` are recursive. Haskell, for instance, needs no such keyword for similar recursive types, so obviously it is possible to build such a thing into a compiler.

So again, why do we need the `indirect` keyword?

Comment: I believe the Swift team added a keyword when they made recursive enums possible in Swift 2 because the recursive enum internals bypass usual compiler optimizations for enums, and they wanted to be sure that a recursive enum would be obvious in the source code compared to a normal enum. But I have no official source to confirm this...

Comment: Interesting idea, but why would a developer need this to be made obvious? It's really the compiler that needs to know this, and as I said, it's something that a compiler can figure out. In fact, we know the compiler _does_ figure this out, because if an enumeration is recursive and you don't include the keyword, you'll get a compilation error.

Comment: I think it's not really an issue with the compiler's abilities - rather a decision that goes with Chris Lattner's and his team's vision about what they want Swift to be like.

Comment: Fair enough. I just find it to be a very strange choice.

Answer (score -1):

Swift doesn't *want* to figure this out. It wants to be told explicitly, so it's sure that the code that you wrote is the code that you wanted to write.

Comment: So why not a keyword on recursive methods, too? They seem far more dangerous to neophyte developers in my opinion than recursive enumerations. It seems like an odd choice just to "protect" us from ourselves.